# Javac and SciTE

Tags: java, javac, scite

I'm using SciTE as my text editor.

How can I link Java (JDK) and SciTE such that when I run my code through the compiler, it gets compiled through javac?

I get the error 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, like which operating system are you using? How did you set up your editor to use javac?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Windows because of the error message. Go to Control Panel by clicking Windows key and R and typing control. Then click enter. Now click System then click Advanced system settings > Enviroment variables.
Then set your PATH variable to where you installed your JDK.